# how extract some informations from range of sheet1 and put it on a combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, range, extract

[image]

I am facing a little problem, I have a userform which contains two comboboxes, a combobox1 for "company name" and another combobox2 for "specialty"
I really want that when I choose for example like in the photo, I choose in combobox1 "teter", I want to display in combobox2 a list which contains only MP and PDP
and if I choose teterss in combobox1, I would like to display in combobox2 only PDP, I tried this in combobox2 which allows you to search only in column H compared to the choice I chose in combobox1 but it does not work

```
Dim i As Long
  Dim isearch As Long
isearch = Worksheets("FRS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To isearch
      If Trim(sheets7.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(Combobox1.Value) Then

        Combobox2.Value = sheets7.Cells(i, 8).Value

        Exit For
      End If
    Next i
```

Thanks

Comment: Not enough info. Is your combobox1 based on "company" column? Do I understand properly that if I select value "teter" in combo1 then it means that combo2 should be filled with two values: 1st is - 6 columns to the right and 2d is also 6 columns to the right and one row below (if values are not the same)?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Not enough info. Is your combobox1 based on "company" column? YES...Do I understand properly that if I select value "teter" in combo1 then it means that combo2 should be filled with two values: YES TWO VALUES ON COMBOBOX2 : MP and PDP, because in the first line "teter" has MP on the 8th column , and in the line 3 , "teter" has PDP on the 8th column so if combobox1 contain teter, combobox2 contain PDP and MP

Comment: @axel: If you just want to change the combo2 items why do you iterate between the cells of the sheet? If the combobox1 value is unchanged, how the two options (teter and teterss) will be taken in consideration? Do you want to suggest that you firstly change the value of combo1, then iterate on the page and according to the combo1 set value the combo2 will be cleaned and specific items will be loaded? Even if this is what you try to suggest,  how `sheets7.Cells(i, 8).Value` will interfere in the problem?

Comment: @axel Okay, that's in. Some more clarification - are values in "company" columns unique or there may be duplicates?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak is not unique, because like the picture, in the line 1 and 3, I have the same name of company but the specialty are different  so normally if I choose combobox1:"teter" , the combobox2 should contain MP and PDP and I then I choose between him If combobox1:teterss the combobox2 should contain only PDP

Comment: @axel ok, let me post an answer, note I suppose that the cell with "NOM STE" is A1

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak yes

Answer (score 0):

Change `sheets7` to `Sheet7`  That way intellisense will pick up the range object.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim isearch As Long
isearch = Worksheets("FRS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To isearch
     If Trim(Sheet7.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(Combobox1.Value) Then

        Combobox2.Value = Sheet7.Cells(i, 8).Value

      Exit For
      End If
Next i
```

Comment: What that `Sheet7` should be? If it set it as object before, he could name it whatever he wanted. Otherwise, the code will not accept it like worksheet, anyhow... Maybe `Worksheets("Sheet7")`,  but in such a case he would receive an error and he din not mention something about it...

Comment: @FaneDuru  agreed, but its tough to tell what is truly going on with the limited code the OP provided and the description of "but does not work".

Comment: Agreed... Besides all that, the code presented is far away from his explanations/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The combo box value can be set in that way but it is not wise. It is good to check if the string of that cell exists between that combo items collection. I try this answer supposing that you know some VBA and your code wants to do something. Otherwise, your explanation does not match the code you presented...

```
Dim i As Long, isearch As Long, cbIt as Long

isearch = Worksheets("FRS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To isearch
      If Trim(sheets7.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(Combobox1.Value) Then
          cbIt = ComboIt(Me.ComboBox2, sheets7.Cells(i, 8).Value)
          If cbIt = -1 Then 
            Me.ComboBox2.AddItem sheets7.Cells(i, 8).Value
            Me.ComboBox2.Value = sheets7.Cells(i, 8).Value
          Else
            Me.ComboBox2.ListIndex = cbIt  
          End If  
          Exit For
      End If
 Next i
```

You need a way to find the combo listIndex for that specific string. Which MUST BE PART OF THE COMBO ITEMS COLLECTION.
I just suppose that `sheets7` has been previously correctly set...

```
Function ComboIt(cb As ComboBox, strIt As String) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  If cb.ListCount > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To cb.ListCount - 1
        If cb.List(i) = strIt Then ComboIt = i: Exit Function
    Next i
  End If
  ComboIt = -1
End Function
```

If your code does not count, based on your explanation, you should clear the combo and add one or two items according to the combobox1 value, not with the checked range...
Something like that:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Me.ComboBox1.value = "teter" Then
        Me.ComboBox2.Clear
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "MP"
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "PDP"
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.value = "teterss" Then
        Me.ComboBox2.Clear
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "MP"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the two first codes doesn't work, I don't know why, even if i put him on privatesub combobox2_change () , when I choose from combobox1 teter , the combobox2 show nothing ; same with teterss, the combobox2 show nothing
here is my file 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n9ZbLtmqz1Eiys9yx991OmN0fjXdNU7e

Comment: the third code will not work for me because I want to add more names companies

Comment: the third code work well, but when I will add another names of companies I need to change the code

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand what you really need, sorry... Who and when the items of the combo keeping the company names have been introduced? How to help you if you do not exactly describe what you need? In the first two codes I tried to make your trial workable. Can you explain what YOUR POSTED CODE have/is necessary to do?

Comment: I want like your last code, it's works,thats what I want,  but what about if i have 100 names on combobox1 ? should edit every time ?

Comment: @axel: Your project misses some things in order to be easily understood. Firstly, you must use `Option Explicit` on top of each module/form code. Then you must relevantly name your controls. When you see 'CommandButton1` it is difficult to understand which button is it and what to expect it does. Naming a whole column 'LISTERFS' and add it like `RowSource` of a combo is not the best idea, too.  Don't you need unique values for that combo? From three filled rows, two of them keep the same value ('teter'). You are talking about 'companies', but I couldn't understand where those comp are kept...

Comment: @axel:  In order to "do" something automatic when you have 100 names, **you must define rules able to be interpreted by the code**. Otherwise, do you expect that the code would be able to understand your future needs without defining what is to be analyzed?

Comment: @axel: I made some modifications in your file, which can be downloaded from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1byqtlevh3y_O3IAcPYIxoxMBe26z6uvl/view?usp=sharing. It will stay there for a week. I created a dynamic range which will be automatically updated when values will be input in column A. I renamed your controls in a way to better find them when look at code. Please test, try to understand it and let me know if something unclear.

Comment: The values in the dynamic named range will be unique. Anyhow, I suppose that the must be unique, anyhow...

Comment: thank you very much for your effort, i am not strong in vba and i am just for making a small application so i don't know a lot of advanced methods. Regarding the file you gave me, I will try to explain in another way, I have two companies (for now), the company "teter" gives me MP and PDP, while "teterss" gives me PDP only; in the BUYING sheet, when I click on the blue button, two comboboxes are displayed, the first is combofrs, which contains the list of company names, I did not find, according to my level, that affect LISTEFRS in ROWSOURCE; now let's go to what is important

Comment: , when I select for example "teter" it must display in the second combobox which is combo box, it must display me just MP and PDP, why? because in the FRS sheet, I have teter gives me MP and PDP. your third code works for this particular case but when I add other company names, the third code will no longer be valid

Comment: So, let us clarify some issues: Al modified was in UserForm3. Is that the one you are talking about? If yes, there is no more any 'second combo box'? Which is its name?

Comment: If we are talking about the same form, your 'second combo box' is 'cbospe'. At least, this is what I deduced seeing your similar data in column called 'SPECIALITE'...

Comment: I talk about userform called achatfrs and the name of second combobox is combospe

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand too much from what you are doing... You attached a workbook with a button on the active sheet, pointing to 'UserForm3". I made there the modifications I deduced from your story. Now, you are talking about 'achatfrs'. OK, I made there the modifications, but the logic behind the code of the  'Combospe' combo is strange, if I understood correct what you want. So, is it allowed to have the same 'company' more then once? And do you want to treat it in combo according to its row number? I am totally confused... Please concentrate a little and clearly explain your need.

Comment: I mean that enumeration from A:A column containing 'teter' twice is a mistake, or it is allowed to be there more then one time? If yes, your code iterating through the records of column H:H and exiting at first occurence is wrong. It will always return "MP". If more then one time a company can apear in A:A and you need to reach the row from where the company name has been extracted, you must proceed in a different way. If you must have unique companies, please state that and delete the second occurrence.  Otherwise, I am afraid I cannot help you any more...

Comment: @axel: I updated the workbook in the way I could deduce what you intend to do. Please check it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WvR3lkcwzYV-WBryPRujlUIh6B2YeBTP/view?usp=sharing. I updated 'achatffrs' form and 'UserForm3', too. I renamed this one in 'frmAppl'. Please try to understand the code. Practically, I recreated 'LISTEFRS' in order to keep only the cells in A:A containing data. Then, the upate of the 'second list box' is done automatically from the first one change event. Please, also check 'frmAppl'. I updated all buttons. It seems to me that 'RECHERCHER' is simlar to 'MODIFIER'.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding items to a second combobox**

Assuming you want rebuild your list by entering one or several "row" items each time you choose another value in `ComboBox1` and assuming your sheet's CodeName actually is `sheets7`, I'd suggest the following steps:

- just clear contents in combobox2,
- use the `.AddItem` method to add comboitems in a list,
- omit the `Exit For` and
- set the `.ListIndex` to the first item in the list if only one item to choose

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   Dim isearch As Long
   isearch = Worksheets("FRS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   With Me.ComboBox2
        .Clear
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To isearch
             If Trim(sheets7.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(ComboBox1.Value) Then
                 .AddItem sheets7.Cells(i, 8).Value
             End If
         Next i
        If .ListCount > 1 Then  ' several items
            .ListIndex = -1     ' no concrete display, let open for choice
        Else
            .ListIndex = 0      ' display single item
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Further hint: instead of using `AddItem` you could also populate an array and assign it to the `.List` property via one code line, but the above approach should show you the way :-)

Further assumption: "specialty" items seem to be unique per chosen identifying name.

**Edit due to comment**

Your issue seems to be caused by adding the ".RowSource` property to you comboboxes.

1. I added a simple **`UserForm_Initialize`** event procedure removing this property by code as first step, so you can control it.
2. **Remove** or outcomment a `Combobox2_Change` (Combospe_Change) event procedure **overwriting** prior results!
3. Seems that you named the data worksheet "FRS" `sheets7` equalling the sheets Codename `feuil7` (Excel worksheet name "FRS") - change that to your needs. Furthermore I sticked to ComboBox1 (`Combofrs`) and ComboBox2 (`Combospe`) ... *Bonne chance* :-)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Me.ComboBox1               ' << (Me.Combofrs)
    .RowSource = ""             ' << remove existing row source !

    Dim frs As Collection
    Set frs = New Collection
  ' get unique elements of suppliers/fournisseurs (e.g. teter, teterss, test)
    Dim fr
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each fr In sheets7.Range("listefrs")    ' << feuil7.
       frs.Add fr, fr
       If Trim(fr) = vbNullString Then Exit For
    Next
  ' populate supplier/fournisseurs combo with unique elements
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To frs.Count
       .AddItem frs(i) & ""
    Next

End With

'(Combospe)
ComboBox2.RowSource = ""         ' << remove existing row source !

End Sub
```

Comment: your code give me wrong results, normally if I choose combobox1:"teter" , the combobox2 should contain MP and PDP and I then I choose between him
If combobox1:teterss the combobox2 should contain only PDP

Comment: Does this meet your needs (forgot the `ComboBox2.Clear` method)?

Comment: here is the file, sheet BUYING , https://drive.google.com/open?id=1buMVgeLtAb5nVLcW0W7AjVW9b376qpio i tried your code on combofrs (combobox1)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I am unable to comment as I am not logged in. Please see edits below.

Here's a suggestion of a smarter way to fill out your comboboxes. You may use Dictionary object (Scripting.Dictionary) to avoid repeated values on your dropdown.

Dictionary is similar to Collection which has a set of Keys (unique) with its corresponding values. You may read on [this link](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) to learn more about Dictionary.

**Variables used:**

`companyNamesRange` = range of your Company Names

`dict` = Scripting.Dictionary object

`cboCompanyName` = ComboBox1

`specialty` = value of specialty

`cboSpecialty` = ComboBox2

**And now for the code...**

Add this to your userform's code -- `UserForm_Initialize()` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    totalRows = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get total rows
    Set companyNamesRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & totalRows) 'range of company values
    Call GetCompanyNameList 'this method will fill add unique items on your Combobox1 (Company Name)
End Sub
```

For Combobox1 (Company Name), you may use this edit and use the code below to get unique values

```
Private Sub GetCompanyNameList()
    'create dictionary object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'loop through each Company Name
    For Each cellRange In companyNamesRange
        'test if Company Name exists on the dictionary Keys
        If Not dict.Exists(cellRange.Value) Then
            'since we confirmed that the value is unique, add the value as a dictionary key so that we can collect unique values for testing later on
            dict.Add cellRange.Value, ""
            'add value to cboCompanyName(Combobox1)
            cboCompanyName.AddItem cellRange.Value
        End If
    Next
    'dispose object
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Added method here for `cboCompany_Change` event

```
Private Sub cboCompanyName_Change()
    cboSpecialty.Value = ""
    cboSpecialty.Clear
    Call GetSpecialtyList
End Sub
```

For Combobox2 (Specialty), you may edit and use this as well to get unique values of specialty based on the Company Name selected**

```
Private Sub GetSpecialtyList()
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each companyRange In companyNamesRange
        If cboCompanyName.Value = companyRange.Value Then
            specialty = Sheet1.Range("B" & companyRange.Row).Value
            If Not dict.Exists(specialty) Then
                dict.Add specialty, ""
                cboSpecialty.AddItem specialty
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help, the first code should I put in on privatesub combobox1_change()  ?

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my whole [UserForm(Code)] module. I hope I understood everything correct.

Read comments, ask if you have questions.

```
Option Explicit

Dim dataSheet As Worksheet


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() ' update UserForm name if needed
Dim companyRange As Range, cr As Range
Dim startRow As Long, columnNo As Long

Set dataSheet = ActiveSheet ' replace ActiveSheet with your data sheet name, don't use ActiveSheet

startRow = 2 ' as I suppose - values start from 2d row, 1st one - is the header, update if needed
columnNo = 1 ' as I suppose - starting column is 1, update if needed

With dataSheet
    Set companyRange = Range(.Cells(startRow, columnNo), .Cells(Rows.Count, columnNo).End(xlUp)) ' assign companies range
End With

With ComboBox1  ' this is a combobox with company's names
    For Each cr In companyRange
        .AddItem cr.Value       ' add companies to combobox one by one
                                ' so if the cell row is 2, it will have a 0 ListIndex in combobox
    Next
End With

End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim item1 As Range, item2 As Range

Set item1 = dataSheet.Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 8) ' see the explanation below this part of code
Set item1 = dataSheet.Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 3, 8)

'when we were adding items to combobox1, the cell on the sartRow=2 has row number 2 and a 0 ListIndex in combobox1 (cell on the row 3 has ListIndex 1, and so on)
'so in order to get the row of selected item - we need to add 2 to item's ListIndex

    With ComboBox2
        .Clear  ' clear the combobox2 upon each change, consider it if you have something in your ComboBox2_Change() event
                ' 'cos if there is some selected value the .Clear statement will trigger that event

'           This point is still not clear to me, so there are 2 options based on original post
'           uncomment if needed
'   Option 1
        If Not item1 = item2 Then   ' as I understood, if ites are different we add two of them
            .AddItem item1.Value
            .AddItem item2.Value
        Else
            .AddItem item1.Value          ' if they are the same - we add only one
        End If

'   Option 2
'       If ComboBox1.Value = "teter" Then
'           .AddItem "MP"
'           .AddItem "PDP"
'       ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "teterss" Then
'           .AddItem "MP"
'       End If
    End With
End Sub
```